# How to get the records of table A, which are in one row in table B

Tags: sql

```
SELECT ClaimID, CPTCode FROM TABLEA

ClaimId CPTCode
  **60  62000**
  **60  0213T**
  60    99383
  60    93230
  60    96372

SELECT cpt1,CPT2 FROM TABLEB

cpt1    CPT2
**62000 0213T**
**62000 0230T**
62000   0216T
62000   0228T
```

SELECT the record from tableA only that which is at same row in tableB
Result should be

```
60  62000
60  0213T
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I realize that I don't understand the question.  Why are those rows the ones being returned?

Comment: 62000 is CPT1 while it has combination with 0213T CPT2 code.
so in this case Same claimid which is 60. must not be billed. _
if these cpt lies in different claims then its OK. but I must identify those claimids which contains multiple cpts and those CPTs are in same row. in primary table.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select ClaimID, CPTCode 
from tablea a
where exists (select 1
              from tableb b
              where b.cpt1 = a.cptcode
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from tableb b
              where b.cpt2 = a.cptcode
             );
```

This query can take advantage of two indexes:  `tableb(cpt1)` and `tableb(cpt2)`.

You can write this as:

```
select ClaimID, CPTCode 
from tablea a
where exists (select 1
              from tableb b
              where a.cptcode in (b.cpt1, b.cpt2)
             );
```

However, this version is much harder to optimize.

Comment: This may not be correct as it select those claimid which exist only once in Table hay. 
while the requirement is that get two records from table A which exist as single record in table b. Please recheck when you get time.

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
select obj.ClaimID, obj.CPTCode from (
select row_number() as row_noA, ClaimID, CPTCode FROM TABLEA
join 
select row_number() as row_noB, cpt1,CPT2 FROM TABLEB
on TABLEA.CPTCode = TABLEB.CPT2 and TABLEA.row_noA = TABLEB.row_noB
)obj
```

join two tables and match each row using same row number and get the output